# Is there a .mocha file where I can specify defaults such as --no-colors?

Tags: node.js, configuration, config, mocha.js, dotfiles

I'd like to set some defaults for mocha without having to type them each time. Does mocha look for a config file / dotfile anywhere, as jshint looks for `.jshintrc` and npm looks for `package.json`?

Comment: The accepted answer is now deprecated. I suggest accepting the new one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804446/1740079) to prevent more people from using the old approach.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes. You can create a file `./test/mocha.opts` and in the file you can specify `--no-colors`.

See *mocha.opts* on [Mocha Doc](http://mochajs.org/#mochaopts) for more information.

Comment: This has been deprecated. See @migg's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804446/645511).

Answer (score 51):

Mocha recommends `mocha --config=.mocharc.json`.

There are new formats too, like yaml. See some [examples](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/tree/master/example/config).

---

Old answer:

The default is `./test/mocha.opts`. You can pass a custom path with the `--opts` parameter :

`mocha --opts ./mocha.opts`

Useful in case you don’t store your tests in `test/` folder, but next to code files, for example.

Any name and extension seems to work, so you can even do `mocha --opts .mocharc` if you want it to go well with `.jshintrc`, `.babelrc` and the like.

Comment: This is (or at least was), a very obscure function. I had given up hope for such a thing long ago, and thank you for pointing out it's possible now. :)

Comment: THANK YOU! Tests should really be next to files. Locality is important!

Comment: Is it possible for the contents of the file to be JSON?

Comment: It doesn’t seem like so. The CLI splits the content by spaces and then parses it with `commander` module. `commander`’s parser expects a string array. `mocha` source: https://github.com/nishigori/mocha/blob/8ba8416981993de3287b14a80b9ee9d11fe647a7/bin/_mocha#L175 - `commander` source: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/d9abf56c43a93e9584e2e18a9f8fb5af552f738c/index.js#L212

Comment: You could launch `mocha` in a script and pass your JSON file contents. See: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically#set-options

Comment: strange, I couldnt get `--config ./mocha.opts` to work as per their official docs but `--opts ./mocha.opts` worked... thanks!

Comment: This will no longer work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283197/mocha-opts-deprecated-how-to-migrate-to-package-json

Comment: Thanks @MartinCapodici, updated the answer to reflect the newest mocha behavior

Answer (score 37):

In mocha 6+ the `mocha.opts` was changed to `legacy` and the new place to define your configuration is a `.mocharc` file that can have different formats (JSON, YAML, JS) as [described in the docs](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs) or a JSON config added to the `package.json` using `mocha` key.

Specifying your own path to mocha config is done using `--config <file>` but mocha uses any `.mocharc.*` file as default in order described in the docs (JS, YAML, YML, JSON) and also automatically uses `mocha` key from `package.json` with lower priority than a given config file.

Comment: An example .mocharc.js file is here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js (and there are other formats in that directory as well).